# @wire returns data as object but it's not possible to read fields in js

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Let's say we have

```
@wire (getPPM, {accountId: '$recordId'}) getPPM(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data && typeof data.summaries!== 'undefined') {
           console.log(data.summaries);
       }

    }
```

in console i can see:

```
{data: {…}, error: undefined}
.   data:
.   summaries: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

but data.summaries is always undefined. what am i doing wrong?

```
public with sharing class PPMDataWrapper {
public String org62AccountId;
@AuraEnabled public List<Summaries> summaries;

/**
 * @description inner class for Program Summaries 
 */
public class Summaries {
    @AuraEnabled public Map<String, String> measurements;
    @AuraEnabled public String programType;
    @AuraEnabled public String totalPoints;
    @AuraEnabled public String programSummaryId;
    @AuraEnabled public String rankName;
    @AuraEnabled public String startDate;
    @AuraEnabled public String endDate;
    @AuraEnabled public String periodName;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a wrapper class to return data? Can you show us what that looks like?

Comment: Your variable `data` contains two fields, `data` and `error`. So you should use `data.data.summaries`. You may want to rename your variable to result or something similar.

Comment: as i said i can see in developer console data object

Comment: Yes, data is an object, containing two members, called `data` and `error`. The `data` part contains the actual returned data. It's confusing because you named your variable data as well.

Comment: we clearly see 2 entries in summaries how is it undefined your way of accessing it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rael_kid pointed out you're accessing `summaries` in wrong way. Your param is named `data` and it has `data` and `error` property. So to access `summaries` you should write

```
console.log(data.data.summaries);
```

As a good practice and to avoid confusion, you should use [JavaScript Object Destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring) assignment for wired method param. Here's updated wired method with JS Object Destucturing syntax.

```
@wire(getPPM, {accountId: '$recordId'})
getPPM({data,error}) {
    if(!error){
       console.log(data.summaries);
    }else{
       console.error(error);
       //or perform additional error handling
    }
}
```